# Decorator that covers all methods and passes automatically first parameter

Tags: java, decorator

I have class `BaseClass` that contains a few methods like

```
public Result mothodA(Token token, String arg1, String arg2);

public Result mothodB(Token token, String arg1);

public OtherResult mothodC(Token token, String arg1, String arg2);

...
```

Is it possible to decorate this class somehow to pass automatically `Token` argument (which will be stored in decorator) ?

Expected output:

```
DecoratedBaseClass decorated = new DecoratedBaseClass();
Result result = decorated.methodA("arg1", "arg2");
OtherResult otherResult = decorated.methodC("arg1", "arg2");
```

I bet it's not possible, but maybe I don't know about some tricks with decorators.

Comment: You could have a constructor that takes Token?

Comment: I can't modify `BaseClass` right now - it's generated with WSDL file. I will create `Token` object in `DecoratedBaseClass` constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You change the interface of `BaseClass` so this has nothing to do with decorator its more an adapter.

> **Decorator**
>   Attach additional responsibilities to an object dynamically **keeping the same interface.**

Build a `BaseClassAdapter` and delegate the calls to `BaseClass`.

```
public class BaseClassAdapter {

    private final BaseClass baseClass;
    private final Token token;

    public BaseClassAdapter(BaseClass baseClass){ 
       this.baseClass = baseClass;
       this.token = ...;
    }

    public Result mothodA(String arg1, String arg2) {
       baseClass.mothodA(token, arg1, arg2);
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DecoratedBaseClass decorated = new DecoratedBaseClass(token);
```

Constructor in DecoratedBaseClass

```
//constructor in baseclass
public DecoratedBaseClass(Token token) {
    this.token = token;
}
```

Comment: Sure thing, but I want to avoid creating `method[A-Z]` in decorator and do it magically. Methods in `BaseClass` needs first parameter and I can't modify them to get value from parameter.

Comment: If you use Spring you could use dependency injection.

Comment: Unfortunately this project can't use Spring.

Comment: To pass this `Token` param in the background. I want to call `decorated.methodA("arg1", "arg2");` instead of `decorated.methodA(token, "arg1", "arg2");`